# AutoMapper objects with different property types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I want to map my Entity Framework entities (generated from a legacy database) to custom DTO objects (which should be nice and clean).

My legacy DB has entities looking a bit like this:

```
internal class Order {
    int id;
    string Shipping_date;
    string quantity;
}
```

And I want to map it to a nicer DTO object:

```
public class OrderDto {
    int id;
    DateTime? ShippingDate;
    int Quantity;
}
```

I have written an "entity container" to provide dependency injection, which returns values this way:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderDto> GetPaginatedOrders(int page, int pageSize)
{
    return this.db.Orders
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.id)
               .Paginate(page, pageSize)
               .Project()
               .To<OrderDto>()
               .AsEnumerable();
}
```

So: change of types, and change of property names.

Were it only change of property names, it would be easy-but-tedious:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Quantity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.quantity))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.ShippingDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Shipping_date));
```

This is not enough with type changes. I tried a whole bunch of stuff:

- Parsing the properties at the mapping declaration, like `src => int.Parse(src.quantity)` but Linq doesn't like it.
- Extending the EF entities with custom properties like `QuantityInt { get { return int.Parse(this.quantity) } }` and using these in the mapping, but AutoMapper doesn't like it, and explicitly don't support them.
- Mapping system types one to another like `Mapper.CreateMap<string, int>().ConvertUsing(Convert.ToInt32)` but I still get `Unable to create a map expression from System.String to System.Int32` errors.
- Using custom converters for my class, but I always get empty values from `ResolutionContext.SourceValues` at run-time from my entities (I'm guessing that they are disposed before AutoMapper gets them or something like this).

I'm realizing that AutoMapper is convention-based, so maybe I should use another tool, but which one exist?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess you're mapping inside db query (linq), but not the final object itself (after calling ToList, First, Single etc). So I guess you should query your entity first and then try to map.

Comment: Out of curiousoty, are you using `Mapper.Map<T>(...)` to map your queries or are you doing `.Project().To<T>()` from the Queryable Extensions namespace under `Automapper.QueryableExtensions`?

Comment: I have added a usage sample to the question ; I'm using Project().To() on the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Project() uses Linq to entities, which generates SQL and naturally only understands a very limited set of functions.

If you use

```
Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Order>, IEnumerable<OrderDto>>(src)
```

your conversions will work fine.

Comment: The conversions work fine, but you loose all the benefits of `.Project()`.

Comment: How do I use this with my enumerables ?

Comment: Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Order>, IEnumerable<OrderDto>>(src)

Comment: I might lose the benefits of Project(), but I gain the benefit of it working! Thanks! <3